# Read config file and create a log file

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a config file called `one_two.config.txt` containing the path of a log file to be written.

I want to read this line ( 'comdir=C:\Users\One\Desktop' ) and then create a new log file in a given directory. 
The log file is going to have some data ( Time / Date / ID etc. )

Here is what i have right now :

```
                   string VarSomeData = ""; // Contains Data that should be written in log.txt

                    for (Int32 i = 0; i < VarDataCount; i++)
                    {                            

                        csp2.DataPacket aPacket;


                        VarData = csp2.GetPacket(out aPacket, i, nComPort);


                        VarSomeData = String.Format("\"{0:ddMMyyyy}\",\"{0:HHmmss}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\" \r\n", aPacket.dtTimestamp, VarPersNr, aPacket.strBarData, VarId.TrimStart('0'));


                        string line = "";
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("one_two.config.txt"))
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("log.txt"))
                        {
                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                               if((line.StartsWith("comdir="))
                               {
                                 // This is wrong , how should i write it ?
                                 sw.WriteLine(VarSomeData); 
                               }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Right now the log file is being created in same directory as the config file.

Comment: Do you want to copy file?

Comment: If it is working for you. Than it is fine. Whereas the question isnt very clear. Please add more details to make us understand. What exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @AlekseyL. I want to read a file where i have already written 'comdir=C:\Users\One\Desktop' , read this line and create a new file on Desktop with a name 'log.txt'

Comment: Stop updating your question with more questions. Accept what someone has provided so far that worked and create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
string line;
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("one_two.config.txt"))
using (StreamWriter newfile = new StreamWriter("log.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        newfile.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Input file path
string inPath = "C:\\Users\\muthuraman\\Desktop\\one_two.config.txt";
//Output File path
string outPath = "C:\\Users\\muthuraman\\Desktop\\log.txt";
// Below code reads all the lines in the text file and Store the text as array of strings
string[]  input=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(inPath);
//Below code write all the text in string array to the specified output file
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(outPath, input);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you have a config file containing the path of a log file to write; but you're not saying anything about the content of that log file. You just want to know where to create it, correct?

Something like

```
string ConfigPath = "one_two.config.txt";
string LogPath = File.ReadAllLines(ConfigPath).Where(l => l.StartsWith("comdir=")).FirstOrDefault()
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LogPath)) {
  using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(LogPath.SubString(7))) {
    writer.WriteLine("Log file created.");
  }
}
```

You can also read the configuration line this way with a little bit more code but you'll get better performance

```
string LogPath = null;
using (StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(ConfigPath)) {
  while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if (line.StartsWith("comdir="))
      LogPath = line.Substring(7);
  }
}
```

For the configuration file, you might want to consider using a C# class that you serialize as an XML file and then deserialize when launching the application. Then you have the configuration already available within a class whenever you need it.

Comment: Hello. Have edited my post, there i show what i have now. And the log file is going to contain data like (Time /Date / ID etc. )